# Why is my R session crashing while using rcpp and OpenMP?

Tags: c++, r, openmp, rcpp

I am trying to optimize the performance of my code by utilizing both RcppArmadillo and OpenMP, however, my R session crashes when I run the code with `ncores` > 1.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List A_hj_Comp(const arma::mat& X, int h, int j, double v, double u, int ncores=1){
    arma::mat dat = X.rows(find(X.col(2)==h));
    arma::mat ts = dat.rows( find(dat.col(3) == j && (dat.col(3) != dat.col(2))) );
    arma::vec ts1 = ts.col(5);
    arma::vec ts_1 = sort(unique(ts1));
    arma::vec ts2 = ts_1.elem( find(ts_1 > v && ts_1 <= u) );
    
    arma::mat temp1; arma::mat temp2; arma::mat temp2a;
    int nn=ts2.size();
    arma::vec res1(ts2.size()); 
    arma::vec res2(ts2.size());
    arma::vec A = arma::zeros<arma::vec>(nn+1); 
    double t;
    
    // Added an omp pragma directive to parallelize the loop with ncores
    #if defined(_OPENMP)
        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(ncores)
    #endif
    for(arma::uword i = 0; i < ts2.size(); i++) {
        t = ts2(i);
        temp1 = dat.rows(find(dat.col(4) < t && dat.col(5) >= t));
        res1(i) = sum(1/temp1.col(6));
        temp2 = dat.rows(find(dat.col(3) == j && dat.col(2) == h));
        temp2a = temp2.rows(find(temp2.col(5) == t));
        res2(i) = sum(1/temp2a.col(6));
    }
    A.subvec(1,nn) = cumsum(res2/res1); 
    
    List res; 
    res["ts"] = ts2;
    res["A"] = A;
    return(res);
}
```

The code is saved as case1.cpp. The function is called in `R` via

```
Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS" = "-fopenmp")
Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS" = "-fopenmp")
sourceCpp("case1.cpp")
cores = parallel::detectCores() - 1
A = A_hj_Comp(X=X, h=0, j=2, v=0, u=max(X[,6]), ncores = cores)
```

The data matrix passed into the function takes the form

```
> head(X)
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]     [,5]      [,6] [,7]
1    1    1    0    1 0.000000 3.2321980   94
2    1    1    1    2 3.232198 3.3012580   94
3    1    2    0    0 0.000000 0.4319291   94
4    1    3    0    2 0.000000 3.2867710   94
5    1    4    0    1 0.000000 3.3186400   94
6    1    4    1    2 3.318640 3.3304740   94
```

Session info

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[9] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] RcppArmadillo_0.10.5.0.0 Rcpp_1.0.6               geeM_0.10.1             
 [4] Matrix_1.3-3             geepack_1.3-2            doParallel_1.0.16       
 [7] iterators_1.0.13         foreach_1.5.1            dplyr_1.0.6             
[10] MASS_7.3-54              isotone_1.1-0            Rgraphviz_2.36.0        
[13] graph_1.70.0             BiocGenerics_0.38.0      mstate_0.3.1            
[16] survival_3.2-11          foreign_0.8-81          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] pillar_1.6.1       compiler_4.1.0     RColorBrewer_1.1-2 tools_4.1.0       
 [5] lifecycle_1.0.0    tibble_3.1.2       lattice_0.20-44    pkgconfig_2.0.3   
 [9] rlang_0.4.11       DBI_1.1.1          generics_0.1.0     vctrs_0.3.8       
[13] stats4_4.1.0       tidyselect_1.1.1   glue_1.4.2         data.table_1.14.0 
[17] R6_2.5.0           fansi_0.4.2        tidyr_1.1.3        purrr_0.3.4       
[21] magrittr_2.0.1     backports_1.2.1    codetools_0.2-18   ellipsis_0.3.2    
[25] splines_4.1.0      nnls_1.4           assertthat_0.2.1   utf8_1.2.1        
[29] broom_0.7.6        crayon_1.4.1
```

I cannot understand why `R` crashes. Some explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  We are happy to help here but we do place a premium on _minimally veriable complete examples_ and while you supplied code, you did not supply the data and call to trigger it.  Experience also taught many of us that the term _minimal_ here is valuable: try to reduce your problem down and down to a few lines -- you may just find the bug on the way.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thanks for your response. After spending some hours debugging, I noticed that the code runs smoothly if I avoid using the `arma::find` function in the parallel loop. However, this function is instrumental to my code.

Comment: @Sam it would also be useful if you included info on your operating system etc. Pasting the output of ``sessionInfo()`` will help. Thanks.

Comment: Coincidentally I just answered a related question in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/issues/340).  Maybe if you have _outer_ OpenMP around Armadillo, you may need to tell Armadillo to not use threads too?

Comment: In the RccpArmadillo's config.hpp file `#define ARMA_USE_OPENMP` is commented. This disables the use of OpenMP for parallelization. I tried tweaking other OpenMP settings, yet no luck.

Comment: Also, just in case, note that _in general_ you cannot simply slap a parallel section around segments containing R data structures.  And as we instantiate Armadillo vectors and matrice "zero copy"-style as proxies, this includes them.  See what e.g. the RcppParallel package does with its _distinct_ RVector and RMatrix types.